# Help with differential equation of unknown order

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

I was working with a problem and this differential equation came up.
$$1+\frac {dx}{x}=e^{mx \, dy}$$

I don't think this has any closed form solution. Can anyone solve this if possible?

Comment: I'm not certain in the slightest, but I don't think the exponent of a one form has meaning. However, assuming it does, and recalling that $\mathrm{d}y \wedge \mathrm{d}y = 0$, $\exp(mx\, \mathrm{d}y) = 1 + mx\,\mathrm{d}y$, which is easy to deal with.

Answer (score 1):

The proposed equation :
$$1+\frac {dx}{x}=e^{mx \, dy}$$
doesn't mean anything outside the field of nonstandard analysis, which is probably not the concern of the OP.

I suppose that this equation comes from physical modeling. If so, loosely continuing on the same way : $\quad e^{mx\,dy}\simeq 1+mx\,dy\quad$ leading to :

$$\frac {dx}{x}=mx \, dy \quad\to\quad \frac{dy}{dx}=\frac{1}{mx^2}$$ 
This is a first order linear ODE $\quad\to\quad y=-\frac{1}{mx}+C$

Answer (score 0):

$\because dy$ is a very small change in $y$ so we consider $mxdy$ as negligible. And we know that when $x$ is too small then $e^x$ can be written as $(1+x)$ .So in above differential equation, $e^{mxdy}$ can  be written as $(1+mxdy)$ and the solution for given problem is as follows-

$1+\frac{dx}{x}=e^{mxdy}$

$\Rightarrow1+\frac{dx}{x}=1+mxdy$

$\Rightarrow\frac{dy}{dx}=\frac{1}
{mx^2}$

$\Rightarrow y=-\frac{1}{mx}+c$